# Variable named same as function works ok via Python but not within WSGI script

Tags: python, python-2.7, mod-wsgi, wsgi

This is python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
def a():
        a = 'test'
        return a

a = a()
print a
```

it works fine. the output is:

```
test
```

now let's try this via WSGI:

```
def a():
    return 'test'


def application(environ, start_response):

    a = a()

    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])
    yield a
```

the error is:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment
```

the only way to fix this error is to rename the variable "a" to something else such as..

```
 a1 = a()
```

now there is no longer and error in WSGI.

but why is this ?

Comment: Did you look at any of the other gazillion questions on here about UnboundLocalError?

Answer (score 0):

In the first example

```
def a():
    a = 'test' # define a local variable a
    return a # return the local variable a
```

Both references to `a` inside the function are the same local variable, that you assign then return.

In the second example:

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    a = a() # assign something called a to the result of calling itself?
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])
    yield a
```

You have references to `a` a local variable, and `a` the nonlocal function name mixed together in the same block of code. That's what it doesn't like. It's thinking that if you are talking about the nonlocal `a` then you would need to put `global a` at the top of your method. If you are talking about a local variable `a` then you can't call `a()` because it doesn't know what that means.

I suggest you probably don't want to reuse your identifiers quite so freely.